# Solving $(y’)^2 = |4y|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the equation:

$$
(y’)^2 = |4y|, y(1) = 4
$$

Now i thought to start with assuming $y > 0$ getting:

$$
(y’)^2 = 4y \Rightarrow y’ = 2\sqrt{y} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = 2\sqrt{y} \Rightarrow dy = 2\sqrt{y}dx
$$

Integrating:

$$
\int dy = \int 2\sqrt{y}dx \Rightarrow y = 2x\sqrt{y} + C
$$

Using the start condition:

$$
C = 0
$$

Therefore:

$$
y = 2x\sqrt{y} \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} = 2x \Rightarrow y = 4x^2
$$

I could do something similar with $y < 0$ But that not alike the answers, so probably i do something wrong.

What is wrong?

Sorry for asking so many questions, i am a beginner.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just one little thing. When your first step applies a square root, you are neglecting to consider that $y'$ might be negative. That is, maybe $y'=-2\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me more answers. I don’t understand it totally, what about $y < 0$? Anyway, now i have left to decide between which is not an answer $(x+1)|x+1|$ or $(3-x)|3-x|$, The answers that i got so far: $(3-x)^2$ And $(x+1)^2$ How do i decide between the two? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Since the sign of $y'$ is arbitrary, the given initial value problem has *two* solutions $y_1(x) = (x+1)|x+1|$, $y_2(x) = (3-x)|3-x|$.

Comment: @Christoph Something is not right. The solutions i got are: $(x+1)^2, (3-x)^2$, now you said that the 2 answers you mentioned are also solutions, also we can say that $y == 0$ Is a solution. But, as the options of the answer, one of the solutions must be wrong, but now, following what you said, they all seem fine, so where is the mistake? Which solution isn’t correct?

Comment: All are correct I think. There seem to be four solutions, actually: $\{(x+1)^2,(3-x)^2,(x+1)|x+1|,(3-x)|3-x|\}$. They all satisfy the ODE at every $x$, and they satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: @Christoph ok so something wrong, the question asks which solution isn’t correct, they gave me all the 4 you mentioned + $y==0$ which is the singular solution. So maybe the $y==0$ Isn’t correct because its not satisfying $y(1) = 4$? That is the trick?

Comment: Yes, $y \equiv 0$ is not a solution of the given initial value problem. It is a solution of the ODE, but it doesn't satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: @Christoph Great thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you are integrating $\ \sqrt{y} dx$, and writing it as $\ \sqrt{y}x+c$, you are assuming that $\ \sqrt{y}$ is a **constant** with respect to $\ x$, in the sense $\ y$ is not a function of $\ x$. Hence to solve it correctly without any assumption, we have to separate the variables, such as

$$\ \frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}=dx$$
Integrating we get,
$$\ \sqrt{y}=x+C$$
Then find $\ C$ from given conditions. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes helped a lot and worked for that, yet now i tried to do the same for $y < 0$ And didn’t really get an answer, so i miss some solutions as far as i understand from the answers, do you have an idea how to solve for $y < 0$?